# IOS response button click in another viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here is the main idea

```
+---MyViewController.m----+                        +---BtnOnClickResp.m-----+
|                         |  EventTouchUpInside:   |                        |  
|       Button ---------------------------------------> OnBtnClick()        |
|                         | textView.text=@"blabla"|         |              |
|      *textView <------------------------------------------ +              |
|                         |                        |                        |
+-------------------------+                        +------------------------+
```

I want to test if button `OnClick` could be pressed in another controller like this:

`MyViewController.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextView *textView;

+(id) sharedInstance;

@end
```

`MyViewController.m`

```
#import "MyViewController.h"
#import "BtnOnClickResp.h"

@interface MyViewController ()

@end

@implementation MyViewController

@synthesize textView;

+ (id) sharedInstance{
    static MyViewController *instance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return instance;
}

- (void) setUpScene{
    textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 400) ];
    [textView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [textView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18]];
    [textView setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    textView.text = @"";
    [self.view addSubview:textView];
    UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 50 , 400, 50)];
    [btn setTitle:@"Click Me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn addTarget:[[BtnOnClickResp alloc] init] action:@selector(onBtnClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setUpScene];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@end
```

`BtnOnClickResp.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BtnOnClickResp : UIViewController

@end
```

`BtnOnClickResp.m`

```
#import "BtnOnClickResp.h"
#import "MyViewController.h"

@interface BtnOnClickResp ()

@end

@implementation BtnOnClickResp

- (void) onBtnClick: (UIButton *) btn{
    NSLog(@"btn was click but I am in another controller");
    MyViewController *control = [MyViewController sharedInstance];
    control.textView.text = @" I am setting this content in another view cheers!!!";
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

The main idea is draw/add a button view in the `MyViewController` and make the response to click code in another controller, I thought the action assignment code:

```
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(onBtnClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

if we change the `self` to the actually controller we want to use then the click event will be dispatched to that controller

But it seems not working.

Really a beginner of ios development would be happy if you don't downvote this beginner's question.

### EIDT

After taking the advice as @Mike suggested,

I change the `MyViewController.m` to this:

```
#import "MyViewController.h"
#import "BtnOnClickResp.h"

@interface MyViewController (){
    //here is the change , I made a private ref of the controller
    BtnOnClickResp *respContl;
}

@end

@implementation MyViewController

@synthesize textView;

+ (id) sharedInstance{
    static MyViewController *instance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return instance;
}

- (void) setUpScene{
    textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 400) ];
    [textView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [textView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18]];
    [textView setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    textView.text = @"";
    [self.view addSubview:textView];
    UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 50 , 400, 50)];
    [btn setTitle:@"Click Me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn addTarget:respContl action:@selector(onBtnClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    respContl = [[BtnOnClickResp alloc] init];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setUpScene];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@end
```

Now I could see the NSLog of `btn was click but I am in another controller` but the view content still kept not changed to `@" I am setting this content in another view cheers!!!"` as it expected to be in `BtnOnClickResp.m`

This is the launch code in `AppDelagate.m`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    UIViewController *control = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
    [self.window setRootViewController:control];
    [self.window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using Objective-C over Swift? As a beginner, I would recommend learning Swift over Objective-C as it is where Apple is focussing it'e efforts.

Comment: @JacobKing the reason is that a lot of the compenment we are using are writen in oc only ：（

Answer (score 0):

You are adding Target

```
[btn addTarget:[[BtnOnClickResp alloc] init] action:@selector(onBtnClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

to

```
[BtnOnClickResp alloc] init]
```

is Wrong

Because it will create new instance and add listener to it.
 However you are try to access action in other instance

You have 4 solutions

1. Create shared instance of  `BtnOnClickResp` and assign target to it
2. Pass the `self` of   `BtnOnClickResp` to the `MyViewController` on and assign it
3. Create Delegate
4. Post Notification

Comment: Can you describe it more specifically? don't know what I did wrong with create a new instance of `BtnOnClickResp` and assign a listener to it could be hurt

Comment: Doesn't `addTarget` was designed to add an object to handle the event?

Comment: When you execute `[btn addTarget:[[BtnOnClickResp alloc] init] action:@selector(onBtnClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];` It will create new object of   `BtnOnClickResp` and assign target to it but you want that in your class . but both objects are different

Comment: trying to understand what's happening here :D Let me try

Comment: to understand easily -> before `addTarget` line create object like `BtnOnClickResp *obj = [[BtnOnClickResp alloc] init]`  and NSLOg it .and in your class NSLog self , when they both are same you will get you action :D

Comment: Hey, Mike, check the edit, I change `[[BtnOnClickResp alloc] init]` to a private instance and init that in `ViewDidLoad()` and it seems the controller could receive an event but the content of the view still kept not changed as it expected to.

Comment: Could you pls tell me what you are trying to achieve

Comment: respone to btn click and change conent of textview in another controller

Comment: I am at dinner now will post the appdelagate code in one hour ：）I am changing the rootviewcontroller directly in appdelagate.m

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay, but I have edited the question: 1, put a diagram to show the idea I want to achieve hope that could make things more clear. 2, adding the `AppDelagate.m` to tell how I launch the app.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a property of BtnOnClickResp and set it as button target.

```
#import "MyViewController.h"
#import "BtnOnClickResp.h"

@interface MyViewController ()

@property(nonatomic, strong) BtnOnClickResp onClickRespObj;
@end

@implementation MyViewController

@synthesize textView;

+ (id) sharedInstance{
    static MyViewController *instance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return instance;
}

- (id)init{
    if(self = [super init]){
    self.onClickRespObj = [[BtnOnClickResp alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) setUpScene{
    textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 400) ];
    [textView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [textView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18]];
    [textView setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    textView.text = @"";
    [self.view addSubview:textView];
    UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 50 , 400, 50)];
    [btn setTitle:@"Click Me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn addTarget:self.onClickRespObj action:@selector(onBtnClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setUpScene];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@end
```